# Handling Google Analytics with User Consent Cookie in Communities

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, community, lightning-events, google-analytics

We are setting up a public community (LWR template) and want to use Google Analytics. As there is the Google Consent Mode (see good explanation [here](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/consent-mode-google-tags/)) and the new [Lightning User Consent Cookie Module](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-user-consent-cookie/documentation), I wonder whether I'm on the right track with this kind of implementation (see also: [Use Google Analytics in LWR Sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/advanced_use_google_analytics.htm))

In the Head Markup I first deny the setting of the GA Cookies with eg. `ad_storage: "denied",` . The page then loads a Consent Page where the user can set his preferences via `setCookieConsent(this.consent);` in the `cookieConsentToggle` LWC. To pass this values to the Head Markup I created a custom event which fires onClick `handleClickSetConsent`.

The set values bubbles up to the Head Markup where I make the `gtag('consent', 'update',` call. **The Question is: Is this the proper way to do this?** Thank you very much for your help!

**Head Markup**

```
<!-- Test for consent mode -->
<x-oasis-script hidden="true">
    // Initialize the data layer for Google Tag Manager (this should mandatorily be done before the Cookie Solution is loaded)
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    // Default consent mode is "denied" for both ads and analytics, but delay for 2 seconds until the Cookie Solution is loaded
    gtag("consent", "default", {
        ad_storage: "denied",
        analytics_storage: "denied",
        wait_for_update: 2000 // milliseconds
    });
    // Improve ad click measurement quality (optional)
    gtag('set', 'url_passthrough', true);
    // Further redact your ads data (optional)
    gtag("set", "ads_data_redaction", true);
</x-oasis-script>

<x-oasis-script hidden="true">
     // Update Google Analytics based on user consent
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    window.addEventListener("consentValues", function(event) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(event.detail));
        console.log(event.detail.Marketing);
        gtag('consent', 'update', {
        ad_storage: event.detail.Marketing,
        analytics_storage: event.detail.Statistics
        });
    });
</x-oasis-script>
```

**cookieConsentToggle**

```
    handleClickSetConsent(event) {
        // console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.consent)));
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(this.consent));
        setCookieConsent(this.consent);
        event.preventDefault();
        const consentValues = new CustomEvent("consentValues", {
          bubbles: true,
          composed: true,
          detail: this.consent
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(consentValues);
   }
```

Comment: Were you able to deploy this & confirm it was able to work?

Comment: @JackOdell yes, I it's working fine. But you have to keep in mind, that (at least) the LWR community is a Single Page Application (SPA). So it could be, that you have to update GA for that. See also this [link](https://www.analyticsmania.com/other-posts/single-page-applications-with-universal-analytics-and-google-tag-manager/)