# Does userConsentCookie component control Google Analytics tracking on an Experience Site?

Tags: experience-cloud, cookies, google-analytics, consent-management

We use an Experience Site.  We added our Google Analytics Id to it via **Site Builder** & the site now records page views on GA on its own (we didn't have to write any code to control it).

If we configure a [User Consent Cookie](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-user-consent-cookie/documentation) component to indicate that we do not want any **Marketing** or **Statistics** cookies, will Salesforce prevent Google Analytics tracking on it's own?

Or am I going to add some logic to prevent them?  Like perhaps something [similar to what this person is doing](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/369941/handling-google-analytics-with-user-consent-cookie-in-communities) (although I'll need to do it on the HEAD tag of the Experience Site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately Salesforce did not prevent GA for doing anything. The User Consent Cookie is more a way to store the user preferences. Based on these preferences you then have to execute your logic - see also [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/369941/handling-google-analytics-with-user-consent-cookie-in-communities) where I put together the basic logic.